# Ubuntu doesn't boot after (faultily?) installing GNOME Shell

Tags: boot, data-recovery, passphrase

I followed steps from [this guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/stream-videos-music-and-pictures-from.html) to try to install Cast to TV. When I executed the step "by restarting Gnome Shell (using Xorg: press Alt + F2, type r, and press Enter" things went bad. I think I turned the laptop off using the power button, then could not turn it back on. When I tried to re-install the same version of Ubuntu from a Live USB without losing my files, the installer said no existing operating system was found.

I used Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell XPS laptop.

Additionally I tried to recover my files from the encrypted hard drive on my laptop through a Live USB but needed my **mount passphrase** (to access the encrypted hard drive), which seems to be different from my **password**, which I enter upon start-up every time.

Following [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/) guide, I tried to recover my passphrase, but both commands *ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase* and *sudo ecryptfs-recover-private* didn't give any reaction.

Any help in recovering my files or recovering my ubuntu version are highly appreciated! Or if anyone knows what I might have done with the command "Alt + F2"; "r"; "Enter", that might help, too.

**EDIT: I managed to rescue my files from a Live USB:**

1) had to mount my corrupted hard drive using only password, no mount passphrase

2) running sudo nautilus

3) copying all my files to an external hard drive in the sudo nautilus window

Thanks for your interest and your help, community!

James

Comment: GNOME Shell is already installed by default with Ubuntu 19.10. Were you, instead, just installing the Cast To TV Extension? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Your passphrase should be your password, is it not?

Comment: Thanks for your help and interest, managed to fix my own problem; solution in EDIT!